# EF Core - How many items can a single query retrieve?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking to find the maximum size of a query result that EF will support, if there exists one that isn't memory and bandwidth constrained (or db-specific). Is there a hard limit to the amount of IQueriable entries that can exist as a result of a query (e.g. `dbContext.DbList.Where(x => x != null)` ) in EF Core 6 specifically?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit by default. Once you materialise database query it will return and instantiate as many entities as many rows fits the query criteria.

I would suggest to read more about EF Core 6 performance in docs to get better understanding how to get most out of it performance-wise.

[Efficient Querying - Limit the resultset size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#limit-the-resultset-size)

Comment: You have a lot of rep. Can you help me understand why this question was closed. I feel like my question was pretty cut and dry.